# how to fill textboxs from dataset in vb.net, when executed following code then i got invalidCastException

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, windows-mobile-6

```
Private Sub frmbranch_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load   
  Try       str = "select * from EnquiryEntry Where EnquiryId=" & EnquiryId & ""
            ds = DAL.GetDataSetFromSQL(str)
            Me.cbocustomertype.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows("CustomerType").ToString
            Me.cmbbranch.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows("Branch").ToString
            Me.txtcustomerid.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows("CustomerId").ToString
            Me.txtName.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows("ClientName").ToString
            Me.txtAddress.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows("clientAddr").ToString
            Me.txtMobileNo.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows("Mobile").ToString

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, Me.Text)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Answer (score 0):

use 

ds.Tables(0).**Rows(0)**("Mobile").ToString();

...............

...............

you are missing Index of Rows collection of Datatable

Cheers